# Add new row dynamically with Javascript/JQuery/Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am building a timesheet form that consists of a calendar which enables a user to select a specified date, and search for a project. I have this functionality working. What I basically have is this:

[image]

Once the user searches for their project and press the plus button, that specified project. Which in this instance is Asda the user would then click the plus icon which would create a new row and put it into the table 'task for project. How can you do this in Javascript/JQuery.

Sorry for asking what may be seen as such a basic question, but am still learning Javascript/JQuery.

I currently have the plus icon linked to `project_project_tasks_path( project.id )`. This is just temporary.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="left">
<table border="2" width="" id='projects' class='datatable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number  &nbsp</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= project.project_number %></td>
            <td><%= project.project_name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), project_project_tasks_path( project.id ), :remote => true %></td>
                <!-- link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), tasklist_path(project.id), :as => "tasklist" -->
                        </tr>
    <%- end -%>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="right">
<b>Recently Viewed</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project No.</th>
    <th>Project names</th>
    <th>Project Leader</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <b><center>Hours for Week commencing: <span id="startDate"><%= Date.today.beginning_of_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></span></center></b>
</fieldset>

<!-- Task list table -->
<div style="float: right; width: 300px; padding-left: 20px;">
  <fieldset>
    <b>Tasks for project</b>
    <ul id="task_list">

    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<!-- Hours list table -->
<fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Leave"></td>
        </t>
        <tr>
            <td>TOIL</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="TOIL"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sick</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Sick"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><input id="total" class="total_low" type="text" value="0" disabled="">
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Edited:

I have created a **task_list.js.erb** which is as followed:

```
$('#task_list').html('');

<% @project.project_tasks.each do |task| %>
  $('#task_list').append('<ul><%= task.task_name %>');
<% end %>
```

**Project Controller**

```
 def index
    # check if we've got a project id parameter
    if( params[:project_id].nil? )
      @project = nil
    else
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    if @project.nil?
      @project_tasks = ProjectTask.all
    else
      @project_tasks = Project.find(params[:project_id]).project_tasks
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project_tasks }
      format.js   # index.js.erb
    end
  end
```

From the changes made, it outputs:

[image: Inital Outlook if possible]

JQuery Ui autocomplete code:

```
$(function() {
    function log(message) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo("#log");
    }
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "/projectlist",
                dataType : "json",
                data : {
                    style : "full",
                    maxRows : 12,
                    term : request.term
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var results = [];
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        var itemToAdd = {
                            value : item,
                            label : item
                        };
                        results.push(itemToAdd);
                    });
                    return response(results);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to specify in your question whether your projects will be saved to the database as they are added client side, or will the user submit a form after the projects are added. This will determine whether an ajax request is necessary. From the fact that a project number is assigned this would seem to suggest an ajax request but I can only guess.

Comment: this should get you started, http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the projects displayed, are from an exisiting table called projects. I am trying to get a user to click the plus button which will then add a selected project and put it into a new row

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding to the DOM with jQuery is very simple with the append or prepend method.

```
$('element_to_add_to').append('the html to append');
$('element_to_add_to').prepend('the html to append');
```

Check out the empty method in the jQuery docs as well.

Also, you have some bad markup. The task_list `<ul>` has no `<li>`'s and the table in there has an extra `</tr>`.

Edit: From your updated post, it seems like you want to not only insert a row in a table, but also save the data to your database at the same time. In that case, you'll want to make an ajax call to a controller method which will save the data in your DB. Then add the updated row to the table if the call is successful.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path to your route",
    data: "the data to send to your controller",
    success: function(data){
        // here is where you process the return value from your controller method
        // the data variable will hold the return value if the call is successful
        // you can make your controller return the html to be inserted in your table
        // and insert it from here or just return a status message and build and add
        // the html manually here.
    }
});
```

Comment: I've made changes to my question if that helps

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do now. I added to my answer.

Comment: I have edited my post, which shows a similar ajax request response that I used on a JQuery autocomplete. I undesrant how you can make the controller return the html. However I don't know how to insert it into the table.