# Add row to table with jquery and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a form with fields button and a table. I fill in the fields with data and press add button. Then a new row appears in my table without page reload **---- this is how it's gonna be**

How to do that? Some code below. What am I doing wrong?

this's part from controller

```
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    @employee.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to root_url}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

partial of the table's wrapped this way

```
<table id="empl-table">
<%= render "employees"%>
</table>
```

---

```
<tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>#</th>
</tr>

<% @employees.each do |employee|%>
<tr>
  <td><%=employee.first_name%></td>
  <td><%=employee.last_name%></td>
  <td><%=employee.position%></td>
  <td><%=employee.salary%></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', employee, remote: true, method: :delete%></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

---

_create.js

```
$("#new_emp").click(function(){
  $("#empl-table").append("
                       <tr>
                       <td><%=employee.first_name%></td>
                       <td><%=employee.last_name%></td>
                       <td><%=employee.position%></td>
                       <td><%=employee.salary%></td>
                       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', employee, remote: true, method: :delete%></td>
                       <tr>
                       ");
});
```

**upd1**(_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for :employee, remote: true, url: employees_path do |f|%>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= f.label :first_name%>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name%>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= f.label :last_name%>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name%>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= f.label :position%>
    <%= f.text_field :position%>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= f.label :salary%>
    <%= f.text_field :salary%>
    </div>
 </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Add', id: "new_emp",class: 'button radius'%>

<% end %>
```

**upd2**

[image: terminal]

I used to have this as cell content before(i mean just the string I quoted down the text) for every field(employee.name, employee.position....)but nothing happens now

> 

Comment: Probably a duplicate. you might like this [post] [1]
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896983/add-new-row-dynamically-with-javascript-jquery-rails-3.

Comment: Can you please clarify what happens with this code now? Does it throw an error? If it doesn't throw an error, and it doesn't add a new row either, then the javascript you have isn't getting evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So. I solved my problem using another example app.

This video was helpful http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised[1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)

1.I added respond for js in my controller

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to root_url}
      format.js  
    end
  end
```

my problem was - using this line in create controller **@post.save**

2.Then to add a row to a table I used partial _post.html.erb

```
<tr id="tr_<%= @post.id%>">
    <%= form_for post, remote: true do |f|%>
      <td><%=post.title %></td>
      <td><%=post.body %></td>
      <td><%=post.author %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", post, method: :delete, remote:true %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

3.create.js.erb

```
 <%= @post.save%>    
$("#posts").append('<%= j render(@post)%></tr>');
```

[image]

---

I was also thinking about something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/posts/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data:{
        title:$('#title_d').val(), 
        body:$('#body_d')val(),
        author:$('#author_d').val()
        }
  success:function(data){
    alert("dfdf");
    $("#posts").append('<tr><td>data.title</td>
                            <td>data.body</td>
                            <td>data.author</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**In  _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
 #rest of the code
 <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </p>
 #rest of the code
 <%= end %>
```

**In  appropriate controller Create action**

```
if @article.save
 format.html {redirect_to articles_path}
 format.js
else
```

**In  index.html.erb**

```
<table id = "article">
 <tr>
    <th>select</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Created By</th>
</tr>
    <%= render @articles %>
</table>
```

**Create _article.html.erb (or appropriate name depending on your instance variable)**

```
<tr>
<td><%= article.title %></td>
<td><%= raw(article.text) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'show', article_path(article) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
<td><%#= link_to 'delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, data:     {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

**create a new file under Article view "create.js.erb" and add**

```
$("#article").append("<tr><%= j render @article %></tr>");
```

Comment: after doing this, the Modal used to Edit a new article does not work...Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Action**

```
def create
    @manufacture = Manufacture.new(manufacture_params)
    @manufactures = Manufactur.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @manufacture.save
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to manufactures_url, alert: @manufacture.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Manufactures</h1>
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="manufacture-table">
      <%= render partial: "manufacture_table", locals: { manufacture: @manufactures } %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_manufacture_table.html.erb**

```
<% @manufactures.each do |manufacture| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= manufacture.date.strftime("%b %d ,%Y")  %></td>
    <td><%= manufacture.product.name %></td>
    <td><%= manufacture.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_manufacture_path(manufacture) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', manufacture, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#manufacture-table").html("<tr><%= j render partial: "manufacture_table", locals: { manufacture: @manufactures } %></tr>");
```